# When creating a table with the rest api, how long before it is available?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am creating a table with curl (successfully):

```
$ curl https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/s2g-bd1-001/datasets/integration_tests/tables?key=$BQKEY -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$BQAUTH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"kind": "bigquery#table", "tableReference": {"projectId": "s2g-bd1-001", "datasetId": "integration_tests", "tableId": "0479414158500731"}, "friendlyName": "afriendlyname", "description": "afriendlydescription", "schema": {"fields": [{"name": "field1", "type": "STRING"} ] } }'
{
 "kind": "bigquery#table",
 "etag": "\"p8M0C9D2VWWNeiiBOvzKozM5ryM/W3ReJVrhvIimKGxRGXUdDJZI93w\"",
 "id": "s2g-bd1-001:integration_tests.0479414158500731",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/s2g-bd1-001/datasets/integration_tests/tables/0479414158500731",
 "tableReference": {
  "projectId": "s2g-bd1-001",
  "datasetId": "integration_tests",
  "tableId": "0479414158500731"
 },
 "friendlyName": "afriendlyname",
 "description": "afriendlydescription",
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "field1",
    "type": "STRING"
   }
  ]
 },
 "creationTime": "1403588096488",
 "lastModifiedTime": "1403588096488"
}
```

But then I get a 404 trying to get it back...

```
$ curl https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/s2g-bd1-001/datasets/integration_tests/tables/0479414158500731?key=$BQKEY -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$BQAUTH
{
  "error": {   
    "errors": [ {
      "domain": "global",
       "reason": "notFound",
       "message": "Not Found: Table s2g-bd1-001:integration_tests.0479414158500731"    
    } ],   
    "code": 404,   
    "message": "Not Found: Table s2g-bd1-001:integration_tests.0479414158500731"  
  } 
}
```

To be sure, the table has been created because another call to post it returns a 409:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "duplicate",
"message": "Already Exists: Table s2g-bd1-001:integration_tests.0479414158500731"
   }
  ],
  "code": 409,
  "message": "Already Exists: Table s2g-bd1-001:integration_tests.0479414158500731"
 }
}
```

I was able to create a few like this and be able to see them, but then suddenly the tables just didn't materialize anymore, even though the post succeeds. I should add that I am able to create tables through the web console successfully.

What's going on?!

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the response for the table creation, it is then created synchronously. That means once you receive your response you should be able to interact with it immediately. You can see that with the `creationTime` field in the response.

I'm unsure why you are receiving a 404 for the get method. Maybe add some try logic and wait a second or two in between. The response is the table resource so you might also use that instead of retrieving it again.

PS: Did you omit the POST in the curl when you posted it?